# How can I validate an Autocomplete multiple TextField using React Hook Form and Yup?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I am using Material UI's Autocomplete multiple TextField, React Hook Form, and Yup to validate the form inputs.

When I use Yup.string() for the daysOfWeek, even if I have values selected, it shows the error message. However, if I change it to Yup.array(), the following error is displayed...

> daysOfWeek must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null`
> (cast from the value `""`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be
> sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`

Is there a way I can use Yup to validate Material UI's Autocomplete multiple TextField? Thank you in advance!

This is my relevant code...

```
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        daysOfWeek: Yup.string()
            .required("Days of the week are required")
    });

    const {
        formState: {errors},
        handleSubmit,
        register
    } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
    });

   <Autocomplete
       disableClearable
       disablePortal
       filterSelectedOptions
       multiple
       getOptionDisabled={(option) => option.disabled ? true : false}
       getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
       id="days-autocomplete"
       onChange={(event, value) => onOptionsChange(event, value)}
       options={daysOfWeekSuggestions}
       renderInput={(params) => <TextField
           required
           error={errors.daysOfWeek ? true : false}
           id="daysOfWeek"
           label="Days of the week"
           name="daysOfWeek"
           type="search"
           {...params}
           {...register("daysOfWeek")}
       />}
       value={selected}
   />

   <Typography color="error" sx={errorSx} variant="inherit">{errors.daysOfWeek?.message}</Typography>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a small Sandbox and changed a few things to make it work:

- you should use `<Controller />` instead of `register` for [external controlled components](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) like MUI's `<Autocomplete />`
- as you have to pass a `defaultValue` for `<Controller/>` (in your case an empty array) - you can then use the `Yup.min` method for arrays to test if the user has at least selected one day of the week and get rid of the `Yup.required` test as they both do more or less the same in your situation
- you can use the `helperText` prop of `<Autocomplete />` to show the error message
- you can pass the `ref` from `<Controller />` to the `inputRef` prop of `<TextField />` so that when you submit without selecting a day of the week it will automatically focus the field for the user

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  daysOfWeek: Yup.array()
    .of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        value: Yup.string(),
        label: Yup.string()
      })
    )
    .min(1, "Days of the week are required")
});
```

```
<Controller
  name="daysOfWeek"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={[]}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      {...field}
      disableClearable
      disablePortal
      filterSelectedOptions
      multiple
      getOptionDisabled={(option) => option.disabled}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      id="days-autocomplete"
      onChange={(event, value) => field.onChange(value)}
      options={daysOfWeekSuggestions}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          required
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message}
          id="daysOfWeek"
          label="Days of the week"
          name="daysOfWeek"
          type="search"
          inputRef={ref}
          {...params}
        />
      )}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit ComboBox Material Demo (forked)]

Answer (score 2):

I made an async ,dynamicly and formik autocomplete.

this is  my form file:

```
        const FormSimple = (props) => {
    
    
    
        const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
            name: Yup.string()
                .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                .max(50, 'Too Long!')
                .required('Required'),
            nationalId: Yup.number("Invalid Number")
                .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                .max(9999999999, 'Too Long!')
                .required('Required'),
            correspEmail: Yup.string().email('Invalid email'),
            financeNationalNo: Yup.number(),
        });
        const formik = useFormik({
            initialValues: details,
            validationSchema: validationSchema,
            onSubmit: (values) => {
                if (id !== "new")
                    editData(values)
                else
                    sendData(values)
            },
        });
    
    return (<>
     <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="row">
                    
                    <InputSize>
                        <Asynchronous getListData={getListCountry} onChange={(value)=> {
                            formik.setFieldValue("registrationCountryName",value.nameEn)
                            formik.setFieldValue("registrationCountryId",value.id)
                        }} name="nameEn"
                                      defaultValue={formik.values?.registrationCountryName ? {
                                          nameEn: formik.values?.registrationCountryName,
                                          id: formik.values?.registrationCountryId
                                      } : null}
                                      value={formik.values?.registrationCountryName ? {
                                          nameEn: formik.values?.registrationCountryName,
                                          id: formik.values?.registrationCountryId
                                      } : null}
            
                                      required={true}
                                      showName="Country Of Registration" label="nameEn" id="id"/>
                    </InputSize>

                    <div className="col-12 mt-4">
                        
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit"
                                    disabled={loading}>Submit</Button>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
</>)
    
    }
```

and this is my autocomplete file :

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import {useRef} from "react";

export default function Asynchronous(props) {
    const {onChange, name, getListData, label = "name", id = "id", showName,defaultValue,disabled,required,value,noOption="No Option"} = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
    const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState(null);
    const [loadingApi, setLoadingApi] = React.useState(false)
    const loading = open && options.length === 0;
    let timeOut = useRef(null);

    const getData = async (search = "") => {
        setLoadingApi(true)
        const data = await getListData(search); // For demo purposes.
        // console.log(data)
        setLoadingApi(false);
        // console.log(data)
        if(data)
        setOptions([...data]);
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {

        if (!loading) {
            return undefined;
        }
        getData();

    }, [loading]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (filters !== null) {
            if (timeOut.current !== null)
                clearTimeout(timeOut.current);

            timeOut.current = setTimeout(() => getData(filters), 500);
        }
    }, [filters]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!open) {
            setOptions([]);
        }
    }, [open]);

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            disabled={disabled}
            id={name}
            name={name}
            sx={{width: "100%"}}
            open={open}
            onOpen={() => {
                setOpen(true);
            }}
            onClose={() => {
                setOpen(false);
            }}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            value={value}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.[id] === value?.[id]}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.[label]}
            options={options}
            onChange={(e, value) => onChange(value)}
            loading={loadingApi}
            noOptionsText={noOption}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    name={name}
                    required={required}
                    variant="standard"
                    {...params}
                    label={showName}
                    onChange={(e) => setFilters(e.target.value)}
                    InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        onblur:() => {},
                        endAdornment: (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {loadingApi ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20}/> : null}
                                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```